# Relative interior commutes with cartesian product

Tags: convex-analysis

I have been reading [Convex Analysis by Rockafellar](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9781400873173/html?lang=en). One of the proofs made use of the fact that $\text{ri}(A\times B) = \text{ri}(A) \times \text{ri}(B)$, where $A$ and $B$ are convex sets, $\times$ denotes the Cartesian product of sets, and $\text{ri}(\cdot)$ denotes relative interior.

The book says that this is an elementary result and does not offer a proof, but I fail to see how one can prove it easily.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give it a try, using the characterization of the relative interior
for convex sets $C$ from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_interior):

$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\ri}{ri}
\ri(C) = \{ c \in C \mid \forall z \in C \, \exists \lambda > 1 : \lambda \, c + (1-\lambda)\, z \in C\} \, .
$$

Note that for fixed $c, z \in C$, $\{ \lambda \, c + (1-\lambda)\, z \mid \lambda >1 \}$ is a ray extending from $c$ to the
"opposite direction" of $z$. From the convexity of $C$ it
follows that if $ \lambda \, c + (1-\lambda)\, z \in C$ holds for some
$\lambda > 1$ then this remains true for all smaller values $\lambda' > 1$.

Now assume that $(a, b)\in \ri(A) \times \ri(B) $.
Let $x \in A$ and $y \in B$. It follows that
$$\begin{align}
 &\exists \lambda > 1 : \lambda \, a + (1-\lambda)\, x \in A \quad \text{ and } \\
 &\exists \mu > 1 : \mu\,  b + (1-\mu)\, y \in B \, \quad .
\end{align}$$

As seen above, both relations still hold if $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are decreased to $\tau = \min(\lambda, \mu)$. Then
$$
   \tau \, (a, b) + (1 - \tau) \, (x, y) \in A \times B \, .
$$
Since $(x, y) \in A \times B$ was arbitrary, this proves that
$(a, b) \in \ri(A \times B)$.

The reverse direction works similarly.

Comment: Thanks! That was very clear. I also found a proof for a generalization of the result, but yours is much more intuitive. Here's the link to the generalization: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-253-convex-analysis-and-optimization-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT6_253S12_lec04.pdf